# Integrating EMF and view in plugin project

Tags: eclipse, emf

I created an EMF project and tested using <>.editor project generated by .genmodel file by creating a new project and a file through "Example EMF Model Creation Wizards". Is there any way that a view (in plugin project) can be created directly (probably project & file are automatically created when user runs the application)? I dont want the user to create these things. It should be automated and presented in a view.

Answer (score 0):

In the .genmodel file, set .genmodel --> All ---> Runtime Platform to RCP.  This creates an RCP app that does not use all the plugins of the IDE.  If you want, you can generate your app to run in the IDE... However, for this answer I will simplify and assume you generated an RCP app.  Go into the XXX.editor generated plugin, and into the .plugin file --> extensions.  Add a new (org.eclipse.ui.views) View by declaring a new View extension -- see the Sample View for a template.  Make sure to keep track of the ID you give this new View extension.  Similarly add a new PerspectiveExtension extension.  Add a reference to this new PerspectiveExtension with your unique View ID.  In the View extension, click on the class link, this will create a skeleton ViewPart class. It is a good idea to put a public static final String YOUR_VIEW_ID = "com.yourplugin.ViewID" in that class.

This will get you started and if you added your new view to your perspective, it should be visible when running your EMF based RCP app.